# Managing Daily Quotas with Complex Equation for Resource Allocation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, generalized-estimating-equations, variable

I have a complex resource allocation problem where I need to manage specific quantities while adhering to a daily quota of 3000 tonnes. The allocation is based on various variables, and I'm looking for an equation to solve this problem.

I already have a cumulative resource total (X) spread over 365 days, with an initial quota of 3000 tonnes. I want to estimate a fixed value for Xi that satisfies this equation. Additionally, I need to account for the daily change in the quota, which decreases by the Xi of the previous day.

The formula for Xi is currently represented as:
Xi = (X_{i-1} - X_i) / (365 - i + 1)
Assuming X_1 = 3000, how can I generalize this formula when the initial quota for the first day is 3000?

Furthermore, my original Xi is derived from the sum of two components: "rejection" (R) and "waste" (D), both related to the quantity of fish caught by a vessel (A). D is calculated as a percentage based on received quantity (P), where P = A - R. The percentage is determined by subtracting transformed quantity (T) from P, resulting in P - T = D.

My objective is to adjust R, T, D, and X daily while ensuring that X always represents the sum of D and R. Additionally, T varies randomly between 55% and 75% of P each day.

Could you provide a formula for adjusting R, T, and D based on X for each day? Please include an example for 7 days of production. Also, help me estimate the initial Xi and the value for 'p' to calculate 'T' for each day. For the initial quota of 3000 tonnes, the daily range for A is 150 to 500 tonnes.

I need precise calculations for each day, taking into account all variables. The quota is 3000 tonnes, not kilograms. Please provide specific values rather than placeholders for better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Since you're new here, you may want to take 
our [tour], which has information for new users. This is a MathJax-enabled site.
Please use this facility
to typeset your mathematical expressions for better legibility. For a quick 
guide, check this Meta
CV post: [Instructions on
how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).